# Where can I find a gallery of Pygments CSS files

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting

I googled every possible combination but I couldn't find a list of syntax files. Is there a list of good ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Pygments project now hosts a [demo page](http://pygments.org/demo/) in which all the available styles can be tested.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a (unfortunately not 100% complete) gallery: http://help.farbox.com/pygments.html The URL that @CodeReaper posted below is also good.

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice list of choices with previews here: http://richleland.github.io/pygments-css/

Answer (score 1):

I've never found one all-inclusive "gallery" of pygments styles. For the most part, the builtins are what's actually available.

To see what's available in your environment run the following in a Python shell:

```
>>> from pygments.styles import get_all_styles
>>> styles = list(get_all_styles())
```

Other than that, I would try searching the usual-suspect code hosting sites: Github/Gist, Bitbucket, Google Code, etc. I found a few on there such as Twilight, Solarized and Moria.